# SQL request error

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g

Good evening everyone,

I'm working on a assignment and can't figure out the following, I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Rental (
rental_id DECIMAL(12) PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id DECIMAL(12),
movie_id DECIMAL(12),
delivery_status VARCHAR(64),
return_status VARCHAR(64));
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
movie_id DECIMAL(12) PRIMARY KEY,
DVD_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
title VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
stock_number DECIMAL(12),
director_id DECIMAL(12),
genre_id DECIMAL(12),
release_date DATE NOT NULL,
restrictions VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL);
```

I need to do the following, list the names of all movies that are currently unavailable, rented and not yet returned. And this is my query:

```
SELECT Movie.movie_id, Movie.title, Movie.stock_number
FROM Movie 
WHERE (Movie.movie_id, Movie.stock_number) NOT IN (
SELECT Rental.movie_id,
COUNT(Rental.return_status) AS number_of_unreturned
FROM Rental
WHERE Rental.return_status = 'Unreturned'
GROUP BY Rental.movie_id
HAVING COUNT (Rental.return_status) > 1) AND Movie.stock_number = 0;
```

I definitely have movies in Movie table that are not "Unreturend" but I get `no rows selected` all the time. Any advices or directions to think would be appreciated. Thanks!

I edited this post and added the content of the tables.

```
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (1, 1, 'Amblin', 1, 1, 1, CAST('18-Dec-1968' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (2, 2, 'Duel', 2, 1, 2, CAST('13-Nov-1971' AS DATE), 'R');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (3, 3, 'Something Evil ', 3, 1, 3, CAST('21-Jan-1972' AS DATE), 'R');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (4, 4, 'The Sugarland Express ', 4, 1, 4, CAST('05-Apr-1974' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (5, 5, 'Jaws', 5, 1, 3, CAST('20-Jun-1975' AS DATE), 'R');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (6, 6, 'Close Encounters of the Third Kind', 6, 1, 5, CAST('16-Nov-1977' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (7, 7, ' 1941', 7, 1, 6, CAST('14-Dec-1979' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (8, 8, 'Raiders of the Lost Ark', 8, 1, 7, CAST('12-Jun-1981' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (9, 9, 'E.T. the Extra-Terrestrial', 9, 1, 5, CAST('11-Jun-1982' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (10, 10, 'Twilight Zone: The Movie', 10, 1, 3, CAST('24-Jun-1983' AS DATE), 'R');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (11, 11, 'Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom', 11, 1, 7, CAST('23-May-1984' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (12, 12, 'The Color Purple', 12, 1, 4, CAST('18-Dec-1985' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (13, 13, 'Empire of the Sun', 13, 1, 4, CAST('25-Dec-1987' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (14, 14, 'Always', 14, 1, 4, CAST('22-Dec-1989' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (15, 15, 'Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade', 15, 1, 7, CAST('24-May-1989' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (16, 16, 'Hook', 16, 1, 8, CAST('11-Dec-1991' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (17, 17, 'Jurassic Park ', 17, 1, 5, CAST('11-Jun-1993' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (18, 18, 'Schindler''s List', 18, 1, 4, CAST('15-Dec-1993' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (19, 19, 'The Lost World: Jurassic Park', 19, 1, 5, CAST('23-May-1997' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (20, 20, 'Amistad', 20, 1, 4, CAST('10-Dec-1997' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (21, 21, 'Saving Private Ryan', 21, 1, 4, CAST('24-Jul-1998' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (22, 22, 'A.I. Artificial Intelligence', 22, 1, 4, CAST('29-Jun-2001' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (23, 23, 'Minority Report', 23, 1, 7, CAST('21-Jun-2002' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (24, 24, 'Catch Me If You Can', 24, 1, 8, CAST('25-Dec-2002' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (25, 25, ' The Terminal', 25, 1, 4, CAST('18-Jun-2004' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (26, 26, 'War of the Worlds', 26, 1, 5, CAST('29-Jun-2005' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (27, 27, 'Munich', 27, 1, 4, CAST('23-Dec-2005' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (28, 28, 'Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull', 28, 1, 7, CAST('22-May-2008' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (29, 29, 'The Adventures of Tintin', 28, 1, 7, CAST('21-Dec-2011' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (30, 30, 'War Horse', 30, 1, 4, CAST('25-Dec-2011' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (31, 31, 'Lincoln', 31, 1, 4, CAST('09-Nov-2012' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (32, 32, 'Bridge of Spies', 32, 1, 4, CAST('16-Oct-2015' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (33, 33, 'The BFG', 33, 1, 8, CAST('01-Jul-2016' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (34, 34, 'Praying with Anger', 34, 2, 5, CAST('12-Sep-1992' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (35, 35, 'Wide Awake', 35, 2, 4, CAST('20-Mar-1998' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (36, 36, 'The Sixth Sense', 36, 2, 2, CAST('06-Aug-1999' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (37, 37, 'Unbreakable', 37, 2, 2, CAST('22-Nov-2000' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (38, 38, 'Signs', 38, 2, 2, CAST('02-Aug-2002' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (39, 39, 'The Village', 39, 2, 2, CAST('30-Jul-2004' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (40, 40, 'Lady in the Water', 40, 2, 8, CAST('21-Jul-2006' AS DATE), 'PG13');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (41, 41, 'The Happening', 41, 2, 2, CAST('13-Jun-2008' AS DATE), 'R');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (42, 42, 'The Last Airbender', 42, 2, 7, CAST('02-Jul-2010' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (43, 43, 'After Earth', 43, 2, 7, CAST('31-May-2013' AS DATE), 'G');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (44, 44, 'The Visit', 44, 2, 3, CAST('11-Sep-2015' AS DATE), 'R');
INSERT INTO Movie VALUES (45, 45, 'Split', 45, 2, 2, CAST('20-Jan-2017' AS DATE), 'PG13');
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 1, 1, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 2, 1, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 3, 6, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 4, 7, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 2, 2, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 2, 37, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 5, 1, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 5, 24, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 5, 3, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 6, 13, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 6, 2, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 6, 8, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 6, 1, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 5, 2, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 5, 3, 'Delivered', 'Unreturned');
INSERT INTO Rental VALUES (sequence_rental.NEXTVAL, 3, 27, 'Delivered', 'Returned');
```

Sorry if that is a too long post.

Comment: Can you put in words which are the conditions for a movie to be unavailable?

Comment: A movie is sold out if all copies of the movie are currently rented and not yet returned. That is all that asked in the textbook, so I sort of came with my solution for it.

Comment: can you make a sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try, if this logic is correct, I did not quite understand column naming. You might change last row (`having`) to correct it.

```
SELECT 
    m.movie_id, m.title, m.stock_number -- Getting movie id, movie title, stock number
FROM Movie m                            -- from movie table
JOIN rental r 
    ON (m.movie_id = r.movie_id)        -- joining rental table in movie_id
WHERE 
    r.return_status = 'Unreturned'      -- where return_status is unreturned
GROUP BY 
    m.movie_id, m.title, m.stock_number -- grouping_by (same as select)
HAVING 
    SUM(r.movie_id) > m.stock_number;   -- restricting group by quantity
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it's right, the query suppose to give me movies #1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 13, 24, 37, because just they are currently rented and not returned. That is by simply looking at the table. The right query will be: `SELECT Movie.movie_id, Movie.title, Movie.stock_number
FROM Movie
JOIN Rental ON (movie.movie_id = Rental.movie_id)
WHERE Rental.return_status = 'Unreturned'
GROUP BY Movie.movie_id, Movie.title, Movie.stock_number
ORDER BY Movie.movie_id;`

Comment: How do you determine `unavailable, rented and not yet returned` - I did not quite understand logic.

Comment: It is not the real world logic, this is what a book asked for, so it's sort of simulation of one possible situation.

Comment: Did you achieve your goal?

Comment: Yes, modifying the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to write the code since you are a student.  I'll give some direction though.  In your where clause you're comparing (movie.movie_id = rental.movie_id) and (movie.stock_number = count(rental.return_status).  Comparing the stock_number to the count of returns is incorrect.

1. When returning columns from multiple tables, use a join.  The in statement does a comparison. Count is not being returned.
2. Join movies and the "in" subquery on movie_id.  Create an alias on the subquery so you can join it.
3. Add the count column to the topmost outer select

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the query try first to break it down in the components you need.

In this case you need to compare the number of rented movies against the stock of movies.

So write 2 separte queries:

1 - One that will provide the movie id and the number to movies in stock.
2 - Another for the movie id and the number of rentals. For this one you have to count the unretured.

After you have the two queries, you can use them as subqueries of a higer level query that treats each or these queries as a table joined by the common id field.
And add awhere clause comparing the stock with the counted field.

Example:

Table A: id, name, age
Table B: table_b_id, table_a_id, telephone, address

Query 1: select id, name, age from A
Query 2: select table_a_id, telephone, address from B

```
select Q1.id, Q1.name, Q1.age, Q2telephone, Q2.address 
from
    (select A.id, A.name, A.age from A) Q1,
    (select B.table_a_id, B.telephone, B.address from B) Q2
where 
Q1.id = Q2.table_a_id
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate a detailed explanation.